# How to index terms in lucene.net based on timestamp instead of position

Tags: lucene, full-text-search, lucene.net

I'm trying to index speech text in Lucene.net 4.8 and I would like to search terms based on the timestamps (the moment the term was recognized). I have this data structured in json. My challenge is how to search the terms with a query like: "Term1 and Term2 WITHIN/~ 5 seconds". I was thinking to use a proximity query (SpanQuery) and a custom Tokenizer for this, but as far as I understand it, SpanQuery is based on text position. So this approach is not very useful for this task.

Does anyone have any good advice/guidance on how to solve this in Lucene or any other FT library for that matter?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Am I right in thinking you're converting the speech to plain-text, then indexing that text? If so, wouldn't it make more sense to query on text position (as you point out), rather than number of seconds between the words?

Comment: no, not entirely, speech text is structured in something like:  
[{word:"word1", starttime:17},{word:"word2", starttime:27}, etc....].  I would like to index the words, but be able to search on time position (range actually) => word1 AND word2 WITHIN 5 sec.

Comment: Ah, I'm with you. Sorry this isn't too helpful, but I still see this as an _indexing-time_ problem rather than _query-time_. Working out these offsets in a query is computationally expensive and slow. If instead you can index the whole phrase in a single field, then use a proximity query, you'll have a very cheap and fast query.